# Wouldn't this also be a Bernoulli random, but instead with probability of success $\dfrac{1}{\alpha + 1}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Let $A_1, \dots, A_n$ denote a random sample from the probability mass function

$$P(A = 1) = \dfrac{1}{\alpha + 1}, \\ P(A = 2) = \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1},$$

where $\alpha > 0$.

My understanding is that the $A_i$ are Bernoulli random variables with probability of success $\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1}$. So if we now define a new random variable $B_i = A_i - 1$, then wouldn't this also be a Bernoulli random, but instead with probability of success $\dfrac{1}{\alpha + 1}$?

Comment: What values do you believe that a Bernoulli random variable can have? $A_i\in \{1,2\}$ and $B_i\in \{0,1\}$

Comment: @A.M. But we still have binary values for both, just shifted by $+1$, right? So aren't they both Bernoulli random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli random variables traditionally have the values $1$ or $0$, so the $B_i\in \{0,1\}$ would be Bernoulli but the $A_i\in \{1,2\}$ would not be.

Any discrete random variable with only two outcomes ("binary-valued") is a *linear transformation* of a Bernoulli random variable: for instance, $A_i=B_i+1$ where $B_i$ is Bernoulli. If the two values are $a$, with probability $p$, and $b$, with probability $1-p$, then $(a-b)\text{Bernoulli}(p)+b$ will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused here. So, if $A_i$ is not a Bernoulli random variable, but $B_i = A_i - 1$ is, then what is the probability of success for $B_i$?

Comment: Also, is there a way to prove that $B_i$ has a Bernoulli distribution?

Comment: $B_i$ is $1$ with probability $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$ and $0$ otherwise, which is the definition of a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$ (or possibly $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$ depending on whether the parameter is success or failure).